# SAGA_CMD: select polygon features of one shapefile and save in new shape files

Tags: saga

I want to use saga_cmd to select from a shapefile only the shapes, which have a certain area size and store this selection into a new shapefile. I'm using the following command to filter via the respective area size:

```
    saga_cmd shapes_tools 3 -SHAPES=objects_8_area.shp -FIELD=AREA -EXPRESSION=a > 5.0 -METHOD=0 saga_cmd
```

However, it seems that SAGA is not working - means there is no output on the cmd.

Does anyone of you have an idea what the problem might be?

After the selection will work, I would like to store the selection in a new shapefile with:

```
    saga_cmd shapes_tools 6 -INPUT=objects.shp -OUTPUT=objects_red.shp
```

Or could anyone of you suggest another workaround?

---

I got a solution in another forum.

https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/790705/thread/b9a1d1ae/

Comment: When you manually enter "saga_cmd", from cmd window, do you see a message? You may need to add the saga_cmd path to the PATH environment variable. Or provide the full saga_cmd path in the script.

Comment: Script tutorial - https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/Tutorials/Command_Line_Scripting/

Comment: Hi klewis, thanks for your response. I already added the path to the environmental variable and calculated some more commands of saga_cmd succesfully. Should have mention this in the first post. Sorry! If I use "<" instead of ">", then Saga starts but do not find any results. However, there are values from about 0.2 up to 200m² in the field area. I already tried different settings, but without any result which might be the right one. Also checked manually in the GUI.